# Converting char "a" to number 0 using java function

Tags: java

So I'm learning about functions and methods, and trying to create a function that would allow me to replace a Letter with a Number, thus "a" would be 0, "b" would be 1, so on and so forth. I don't know ascii at all, and have only run into creating a very long if, else statement, but I don't even know if I'm on the right track. I'm trying to find a way to create a function without having to make a long conditional statement and use less line of code.

This is the new code I have written with suggestions:

public class CaesarCipher {

```
/*
 * create function that converts a letter to a number
 * ex. a -> 0, b -> 1, etc...
 */
static char letterToNumber (char firstLetter){
    if (firstLetter < 'a' || firstLetter > 'z') {
}
    return firstLetter;
}
static int numberToLetter (int firstNumer){
    if (firstNumber < '0' || firstNumber '25'){ 
    }
    return firstNumber;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char a = 0;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println (letterToNumber (a)); //suppose to compile to convert a -> the number 0
    System.out.println(numberToLetter (1)); //compile to convert 1 -> the letter b
}
```

}

Comment: So, you should learn about ASCII. In fact, you should learn about Unicode, but start from ASCII. The operation is very simple if you understand what a `char` is and that you can use it for arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is just to subtract the literal `'a'`... which will implicitly convert both your input letter and the `'a'` to `int`:

```
public int convert(char letter) {
    if (letter < 'a' || letter > 'z') {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only lower-case ASCII letters are valid");
    }
    return letter - 'a';
}
```

The nice thing about this solution is that it's reasonably "obviously correct" (with the assumption that the letters 'a' to 'z' are consecutive in UTF-16). You don't need to include any magic integer values.

Comment: So this this should also work in reverse as well. Taking a number and converting it to a letter?

Comment: @neme0025: Yes, but you need an explicit cast to convert the result of the addition back to char: `char letter = (char) ('a' + number);`

Comment: thanks. I'll try that out and see how it goes. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The [ASCII](https://www.google.co.il/imgres?imgurl=http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.asciitable.com/&h=488&w=715&tbnid=2U31hF4tTw886M:&tbnh=125&tbnw=184&docid=JMtOixefP_tDJM&itg=1&usg=__QubE4_0y-O_UdQzChSr7cEMGM0c=&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjooJih9ZfLAhUGCZoKHVTYAJwQ9QEIIDAA) value of `0` is 48, `a` is 97 and `A` is 65. So to convert small letter to 0 you decrease 49 and capital letter 17. Same goes for `B/b` and 1, C/c and 2, etc.

```
int smallChar = 'a' - 49; // equal 0
int capitalChar = 'A' - 17; // equal 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char letter = 'a';
int letterAscii = (int)c;
int asciiOffsetOfA = 97;
int positionInAlphabet=letterAscii-asciiOffsetOfA;
```

Use this with combination of String.toCharArray() and String.toLowerCase() on your input String.